# iOS Swift function with type () -> ()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im unable to create function of type () -> () in Swift with xCode...
so far im at

```
func successBlock() -> Void {
    //code
    return ()
}
```

but this is only () not () -> ()
I want this function to fit the type () -> () because of this function:

```
func loginToFacebookWithSuccess(callingViewController: UIViewController, successBlock: () -> (), andFailure failureBlock: (NSError?) -> ()) {
```

gonna pass the successBlock() func as variable in there.
I have nearly the same problem with the failureBlock
or am I on the wrong way?

Thank you, spinhaxo

Comment: void returns empty

Comment: use completion for your concept

Comment: see this https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`successBlock` is a function.
You need closures.

```
let successBlock: () -> () = {
  // do something here...
}

let failureBlock: (NSError?) -> () = { error in
  // do something with the error...
}
```

If you don't want to store them, you can just define them while calling the method like this:

```
loginToFacebookWithSuccess(
  callingController,
  successBlock: {
    // do something here...
  }, andFailure: { error in
    // do something with the error...
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you decided to go with `func`, pass the function's name without the parentheses. Hence, pass `successBlock` instead of `successBlock()`.

```
loginToFacebookWithSuccess(someViewController, successBlock: successBlock, andFailure: failureBlock)
```

That's because the type of the function `successBlock` is `() -> ()` while its return type is only `()`.

Extra:

1. `()` has an alias which is `Void`: `public typealias Void = ()`.

You can even omit `Void` nor `()`:

```
func successBlock() {
  //code
  //no return statement needed
}

func failureBlock(error: NSError?) {
  //code
  //no return statement needed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are confusing a closure with the result of calling the closure.

You just need to pass `successBlock`, which is a closure of type `() -> ()`. (aka `() -> Void`)

But `successBlock()` represents the result of calling `successBlock`, which may be a void value (aka `()`), not a closure.

Nearly the same for `failureBlock`. Do not pass the result of calling closures, pass closures themselves.